# Scipy linear regression does not include `intercept_stderr` property

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to perform a linear regression on a set of two-dimensional points using scipy. As stated by the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html), the appropriate call is

```py
regression_results = scipy.stats.linregress(x_values, y_values)
```

The documentation states that the `regression_results` object contains the following values: `slope, intercept, rvalue, pvalue, stderr, intercept_stderr`. All of these are present **except the last**.

These values are all present in the dict, but `intercept_stderr` is simply not. I cannot for the life of me fathom why. Here is the simple code I attempted to run:

```py
from scipy import stats

# given two lists nmeq_x and nmeq_y... 

result = stats.linregress(nmeq_x, nmeq_y)
print(result.intercept, result.intercept_stderr)
```

I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-7df9d260a3bb> in <module>
      1 result = stats.linregress(nmeq_x, nmeq_y)
----> 2 print(result.intercept, result.intercept_stderr)

AttributeError: 'LinregressResult' object has no attribute 'intercept_stderr'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is about your scipy version; this feature was [added in 1.6](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/12983), released on 2020-12-31.

Note that the documentation says this:

> For compatibility with older versions of SciPy, the return value acts like a namedtuple of length 5, with fields slope, intercept, rvalue, pvalue and stderr

You must have one of those older versions, then. The `intercept_stderr` field was added recently. Update you scipy to 1.6.

Comment: I came to this exact conclusion minutes ago while manually inspecting my version of the file which implements this (`_stats_mstats_common.py`). I was indeed running scipy==1.5.2, an outdated version.

Comment: @Arya, I have scipy 1.7.0 and am getting the same issue. Any thoughts? This is the only thread on this issue I've been able to find

Comment: It's better to post a new question (linking to this one) than to follow-on in comments—it makes your question more visible, and you can include your traceback. Until then, I would confirm that you're _actually_ using 1.7.0; it's sometimes not obvious that you're not running the Python interpreter you think you are.

Comment: Thanks! Weirdly enough it will only let me have 5 vars as outputs/ converting the tuple to a list does not include the intercept_stderr, but accessing it through x.intercept_stderr works. Hope this helps future people with this issue!

Comment: That’s exactly what the documentation I quoted above describes. If you treat it as an iterable, it only contains the first five values. This was done for compatibility.